# SQL Query to retrieve highest item up to a point in a group

Tags: sql, oracle

The best way of describing this is I have a table of people with their names and ages.  Assume that people with the same surname are from the same family.  I need a query in oracle which will retrieve a list of the oldest person in each family, but not older than a certain age.

Table: person

```
name      surname         age
===============================
James     Smith           23
Sarah     Powell          17
Barry     Smith           31
Mark      Smith           35
Mary      Smith           18
Bob       Powell          30
```

How do I retrieve the oldest person in each family under 30?

Results I'm after

```
name      surname         age
===============================
James     Smith           23
Sarah     Powell          17
```

Comment: What if there are 2 persons with the same age?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select p.*
from person p
inner join (
    select surname, max(age) as maxage
    from person 
    where age < 30
    group by surname
) pm on p.surname = pm.surname and p.age = pm.maxage
```

Answer (score 0):

This version will only require one pass through the data:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       FIRST_VALUE(name)
       OVER (PARTITION BY surname ORDER BY age DESC) name
      ,FIRST_VALUE(surname)
       OVER (PARTITION BY surname ORDER BY age DESC) surname
      ,FIRST_VALUE(age)
       OVER (PARTITION BY surname ORDER BY age DESC) age
FROM   person
WHERE  age < 30;
```

Warning: in the event of a tie (i.e. two people with identical ages in the same family), it will just pick one.

Comment: Interesting - never seen the `FIRST_VALUE` syntax before, when did Oracle start supporting it?

Comment: Since 8i I think - 9i does: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96540/functions46a.htm#SQLRF00642

Answer (score 0):

create table f (name varchar2(32), surname varchar2(32), age number);

insert into f values ('James','Smith',23);

insert into f values ('Sarah','Powell',17);

insert into f values ('Barry','Smith',31);

insert into f values ('Mark','Smith',35);

insert into f values ('Mary','Smith',18);

insert into f values ('Bob','Powell',30);

select * from 
 (select 
  name, 
  surname, 
  age, 
  dense_rank() over (partition by surname order by age desc ) d_rank
 from f
 where age < 30)
where d_rank = 1;

NAME                 SURNAME                                 AGE     D_RANK

---

Sarah                Powell                                   17          1

James                Smith                                    23          1

Also see:

http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/oracle/07-jan/o17asktom.html